# "Não tem problema nenhum"?

Tags: português-brasileiro

Algumas pessoas usam comummente este dizer: "não tem problema nenhum". Pergunto-me: se "problema nenhum" significa "ausência de problema", então "não tem problema nenhum" significa "presença de problema"?

Comment: Não significa isso, não. É um caso de concordância negativa.

Comment: Obrigado! @Artefacto